# Custom Middleware in Django with Exclusions

Tags: django, middleware, django-middleware

I require to check authentication via token during execution of certain views, while some views can be accessed without authentication. 
So, how do i make a middleware and exclude some views from it.
Any other idea to solve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest taking inspiration from the [csrf middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/middleware/csrf/#CsrfViewMiddleware) that Django provides

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class MyAuthenticationMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_view(self, request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs):

        if getattr(callback, 'my_exempt_flag', False):
            return None

        # Authentication goes here
        # Return None if authentication was successful
        # Return a HttpResponse with some error status if not successful
```

And create a decorator to wrap your views

```
from functools import wraps

def exempt_from_my_authentication_middleware(view_func):
    def wrapped_view(*args, **kwargs):
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapped_view.my_exempt_flag = True
    return wraps(view_func)(wrapped_view)
```

Can be used like so

```
@exempt_from_my_authentication_middleware
def my_view(request):
    # TODO
```

Comment: Ohk! I Will try and let you know. **Thanx**

Comment: Well, using decorators is the key. Thanks, solved my problem. For other viewers, try this article too if you can't get the idea:      https://medium.com/@ff73cb034b5a/54fddb2a1679